# How to create new container inside <main> tag in magento 2?

Tags: layout, html, magento-2.1.3, containers

I am working with magento 2 layout containers. I need to create a container inside  and below `<div class="columns">` .

My HTML should be like below,

```
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main"><a id="contentarea" tabindex="-1"></a>
<div class="page messages"> </div>
<div class="page-title-wrapper"> </div>
<div class="columns"> </div>
<div class="my-custom-container"> </div>
</main>
```

If anyone come across this case, kindly help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add like follows in layout XML.

```
<container name="my.container" as="myContainer" label="My Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="my-container">
....
</container>
```